# How to get FDQuery result?

Tags: sql, delphi, vcl, firedac

Hi guys I have a few forms in my application and I have a test button where I want to fire a query taken from another unit. Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
var test : string;
begin
// test :=  Unit1.DataModule1.FDQuery2.Open.ToString;                  
 // Unit1.DataModule1.FDQuery2.ExecSQL;
 // test.ToString;
 // ShowMessage(Unit1.DataModule1.FDQuery2.Open);
 // Unit1.DataModule1.FDQuery2.Active := true;
  Unit1.DataModule1.FDQuery2.SQL.Text := 'SELECT CURRENT_DATE';
  Unit1.DataModule1.FDQuery2.Open();
  // Writeln(test);
end;
```

basically I want to be able to for example take the result array or whatever datatype returns and assign them for example to a TEdit and then change it and so on. I wanted to show the result as a string but could not convert it properly. How would you the store the response? Also please correct my calls if there is something wrong - because my TFDQuery2 has the same argument like SQL.TEXT. Is it possible to just fire that query and get the result in a way that I can show it or use it?

Comment: This is far too broad a question to answer on SO, it would require a short book.   I suggest you google your self a tutorial on working with datasets In Delphi - the first one I found is [here](http://www.festra.com/eng/db01.htm).

Comment: I will look into it.. so there is no way to store the value as text or something? The thing i really dont like about delphi is that anything i google or any error i want to look up is posted in a 10year old forum or isnt available at all :/

Comment: You can stored the results of the query in any way you like.  Probably the most convenient is to store them in a FireDAC in-memory table, FDMemTable.  You can do this as simply as FDMemTable1.Data := FDQuery2.Data.  And Delphi has db-aware controls like TDBEdit and TDBGrid which make it simple to work with table data.  Sounds like your googling technique could do with improvement. To avoid getting stale, gone-away results, include 'site:stackoverflow.com' in your google query.

Comment: thanks fot the feedback MartynA !

Comment: You can access it easily. @MartynA was pointing out that you're asking us to write you a tutorial on how to work with data in Delphi, and that's too broad in scope for this site when there are other tutorials available (including the one MartynA linked for you). There's also a tutorial on writing database applications in the Delphi help file itself.

Comment: yeah I actually found something that helped me for now! site:stackoverflow.com was a good tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `TFDQuery.Open()` has executed the `SELECT` query, you can use the `TFDQuery.Fields` property to access the returned field values, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  test : string;
begin
  Unit1.DataModule1.FDQuery2.SQL.Text := 'SELECT CURRENT_DATE';
  Unit1.DataModule1.FDQuery2.Open();
  test := Unit1.DataModule1.FDQuery2.Fields[0].AsString;
  Edit1.Text := test;
  Unit1.DataModule1.FDQuery2.Close();
end;
```

Comment: I found that yesterday too - its pretty simple but thanks for pointing it out :)